# SSRS Count If Statement

Tags: reporting-services

I have been browsing the site here and trying to figure out how to write an expression or created a calculated field to build a pie chart or graph.  What I need to do is count the different between to fields and group them by criteria.  In this instance, we are measuring dispatch performance of when a unit arrives and when it is dispatched.

```
Count(
iif(Fields!Ship_Date_Only.Value - Fields!Book_Date_Only.Value >= 5
,1))
```

I am sure I don't have it formatted correctly.

So I need to count and group when the difference is

```
1-3 days = group 1
4-5 days = group 2
6+  days = group 3
```

These groups will be in the chart and might potentially need to be a percentage of the total of all shipments as well.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You could do his all in a single expression in your group expression but I would avoid that as it makes it harder to debug.

Personally I would do this in two steps.

1. Get the number of days for each row. You can either do this in your dataset query or as a calculated field in your dataset.

As I don't know what your database looks like I'll show an exmaple of how to add it to your dataset as a calculated field.

Go to the dataset properties, click the fields tab and then click Add=>Calculated Field

Give the field a name e.g. `gap` and set the expression to something like

```
=DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Fields!Book_Date_Only.Value, Fields!Ship_Date_Only.Value)
```

This will give you the number of days between the two dates wich you can then use to group in your chart.

In your pie chart, set the Category Group's "Group Expression" to the following expression

```
=SWITCH(
        Fields!gap.Value > 6, "group 3",
        Fields!gap.Value > 4, "group 2",
        Fields!gap.Value > 1, "group 2",
        True, "less than 1"
       )
```

As switch stops at the first expression that returns `True` we have to list them in reverse order. The final `True, "less than 1"` is there to catch anything that does not fall into any other group. You can set the value returned to anything even an empty string or `Nothing` is you want the result to be blank.

Finally set the Category Group's Label expression to the same as the above.

That should be it.